# Draw on Google Map within Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, google-map

I'm wanting to be able to free-form draw on top of a map within a Salesforce page if possible. I believe this can be done but am having a hard time getting the code to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" >
    <div id="map-canvas" style="min-height: 400px" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            console.log('✵✵✵✵✵✵✵✵ initialize() ✵✵✵✵✵✵✵✵');
            var lat, lon, map, marker;
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log('lat = '+lat.toString()+' - lon = '+lon.toString());
                    map=getNewMap(lat,lon);
                    marker=getNewMarker(lat,lon,map);
                });
            } else{
                lat = 37.77493;
                lon = -122.419416;
                map=createMap(lat, lon);
            }
        }//END initialize();

        function getNewMap(lat,lon) { 
            console.log('❂❂❂❂❂❂❂❂ createMap('+lat.toString()+', '+lon.toString()+') ❂❂❂❂❂❂❂❂');        
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
              zoom: 13,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        }//END getNewMap(lat,lon)


        function getNewMarker(lat,lon,map) {
            console.log('♓♓♓♓♓♓♓♓ getNewMarker('+lat.toString()+', '+lon.toString()+', '+map.toString()+') ♓♓♓♓♓♓♓♓');
            var num = 1;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            //console.log(myLatlng);
            //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Click to Zoom',
            });
            return marker;
        }//END getNewMarker(lat,lon,map)


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 

    var isDrawing = false; //start drawing
        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        overlay.draw = function () {};
        overlay.setMap(map);

// Add a listener for idle event and call getElevation on a random set of marker in the bound
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        var polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map
        });
    $("#map").mousemove(function (e) {
        var pageX = e.pageX;
        var pageY = e.pageY;
        var point = new google.maps.Point(parseInt(pageX), parseInt(pageY));

        var latLng = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(point);


        polyLine.getPath().push(latLng);
    });

        });//end of drawing
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at apex:maps that came out in spring 15. http://www.mstsolutions.com/blog/content/integrating-google-map-using-new-spring-15-visualforce-components this new feature may help you better than cumbersome js

Comment: Did you understand how to draw on a google map inside a VF Page? I'm running in the same issue and I don't find solutions